# SSIS Script task in a 64 bit environment

Tags: ssis, build-process, 32bit-64bit

SSIS (SQL 2005) packages that have a script task that invoke custom .NET dlls throw the following error when run in a 64 bit environment

*The task cannot execute in 64-bit environment because the script is not pre-compiled. Please turn on the option to pre-compile the script in the task editor.*

The script tasks are set to PreCompile=false because the referenced dll is generated by the build process.

The suggested workaround is:

Option 1. With precompiled=True, Open, save and close the package in BIDS after the build is complete 
. This will recompile the reference and generate the embedded 64 bit binary in the SSIS package and will cause the above mentioned error to go away. However, this also means that someone has to manually open the SSIS packages after the build is complete.

Option 2. Stick to 32 bit mode.

Option 1 is the feasible one of the two, but impractical. With 200 SSIS packages - we are short of hands to finish this task every time we generate the build.

Option 2 is out of the question because 32 bit just doesn't scale for us.

Now the questions:
1. Do you folks have a build process for your SSIS packages? If yes, can you share your practices
2. How do you manage script tasks? Are you comfortable bundling the developer version of the referenced dll in your scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not what you want to hear,but  i would suggest exploring the idea of replacing some of your script tasks with custom components. There are plently of samples on codeplex. This would allow easy updates because you would just drop new component builds and the referenced assemblies into GAC.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Pragmatic Works has something (I have never used) called BI xPress which has [something](http://www.pragmaticworks.com/help/bixpress/scr/Compile%20Scripts.htm) which might help.